# Which version of AjaxControlToolkit run 32 bit web application

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website which run 32 bit and I need to update the latest AjaxControlToolkit  version. I search the web and found the latest version is 15. However I didn't find any information about running for 32 or 64 bit. The framework on my website is 4.5. Is it fine to use the latest version of AjaxControlToolkit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax Control Toolkit v15.1 is compiled against x86 processor architecture. There is no x64 version.